# What does this Java G1 GC log message mean?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

This is from a Java process running with a 24G heap, G1GC, on some open source variant of JDK 11.

```
[info ][gc,marking     ] GC(132605) Concurrent Mark (728435.456s, 728445.080s) 9624.269ms
```

1. Concurrent mark is really concurrent in G1 (except for the remarking time)?  Meaning that the time being measured here is not pause time.
2. What does this time represent?  Is this CPU time?  Wall clock time?

I've done some googling around to see what this might be, but I never find what this particular message means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, its not a pause time.
   You can also add safepoint logger to see any additional pauses.
   But otherwise I think all actual pauses are logged in clear way, stating what part is a pause. For example `Pause Young (Mixed) (G1 Evacuation Pause)`
2. It should be `GC(number of GC) Concurrent Mark(clock start time, clock end time) time`
   Where click time is relative time from aplication launch. And time at the end is just how long it took, also real wall time.
   You can verify this stright in the source: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/7ccf4358256a0fef895e4081f90b04f71d21bf9d/src/hotspot/share/gc/g1/g1ConcurrentMarkThread.cpp#L184-L220

```
        log_info(gc, marking)("Concurrent Mark (%.3fs, %.3fs) %.3fms",
                              TimeHelper::counter_to_seconds(mark_start),
                              TimeHelper::counter_to_seconds(mark_end),
                              TimeHelper::counter_to_millis(mark_end - mark_start));
```

If you have enough of logging enabled you should see a line:
`[info ][gc,marking     ] GC(132605) Concurrent Mark 728435.456s`
or
`[728435.456s][info ][gc,marking     ] GC(132605) Concurrent Mark 728435.456s`
Somehwere above, marking the beginning of concurrent mark. (the time at the beginning here would be uptime decorator to gc logger)

printed by one of first lines in sources above:

```
      log_info(gc, marking)("Concurrent Mark (%.3fs)",
                            TimeHelper::counter_to_seconds(mark_start));
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the source.

Answer (score 1):

that is CPU time. In general, the name *concurrent* is there for a reason. Let's see that via an example:

```
public class Del {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        while (true) {
            map.put(new Random().toString(), new Random().nextInt());
        }
    }
}
```

And invoke it via:

```
java -Xms50M -Xmx50M "-Xlog:heap*=debug" "-Xlog:gc*=debug" Del.java
```

In my particular run, the relevant to your question logging starts at this line:

```
....
[0.667s][info ][gc        ] GC(11) Concurrent Mark Cycle
....
[0.668s][info ][gc,marking] GC(11) Concurrent Mark From Roots
....
```

So GC says, OK time to start a "concurrent mark". Notice that is already knows the roots (concurrent marking has to start from *somewhere*, after all). The root knowledge (where the roots are) was computed in the previous GC cycle.

Then look at where that `GC(11)` cycle continues:

```
[0.739s][info ][gc      ] GC(22) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 43M->42M(50M) 4.566ms
[0.739s][info ][gc,cpu  ] GC(22) User=0.01s Sys=0.00s Real=0.00s
[0.739s][debug][gc,ref  ] GC(11) Preclean WeakReferences 4.713ms
...
[0.739s][info ][gc,start] GC(11) Pause Remark
```

Notice that there were *other* `11` gc cycles (`22 -> 11`), while this concurrent one was executing.

I'd like also to point you to this log:

```
[0.739s][info ][gc,start] GC(11) Pause Remark
```

This is a remark phase, some attribute this to concurrent phase, which *is* a STW phase; but notice that G1 track it's time individually.